# How to properly normalize pid coefficient in q15 fixed point

Tags: c, stm32, fixed-point, cmsis, pid-controller

I'm working on a PID controller using CMSIS library on a STM32F4 microcontroller. 
I can't really understand the normalization of the PID parameter. Now I have the three Kp, Ki, Kd parameters of the PID controller and I have to put them in the system. I understand there they needs to be normalized, so I have to convert from integer to q15. Here come the problem. In my case I have:

```
kp = 2.7056
ki = 0.085
kd = 0
```

As I understood, I need to find a factor to have these number rapresentable in -32768...32767, so I use `2^13` as factor:

```
kp = 2.7056 * 2^13 = 22164
ki = 0.085 * 2^13 = 696
```

What I don't understand is if I need to divide the result of the PID calculation or not. If I divide, pid output is zero when the error is low: let's have a constant error e(n) = 2.
In the PID calculation (I use formulas described [here](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/arm_math.h) in function arm_pid_q15()):

```
y(n) = y(n-1) + (kp+ki)*e(n) - kp*e(n-1)
y(n) = y(n-1) + (22164+696)*2 - 22164*2 = y(n-1) + 1392
```

If `y(n-1) = 0`, `y(n) = 1392`. If I divide by `2^13` factor, I have `y(n) = 0` (integer).

On the other hand, if I don't divide the PID output, it is like to multiply the proportional gain by the `2^13` factor.

Can someone help me understanding this?
Thanks.

Comment: `If I divide by 2^13 factor, I have y(n) = 0` - you have `0.1699`. You convert from q15 back to floating point, not to integers. you have `y(n) = 1392 in q15 format` it is equal to `y(n) = 0.1699`. You should put `0.1699` to the controller output.

Comment: If you use a specific fixed point implementation then all the values should be scaled to that. So your 2 should also be multiplied by 2^13 and then the result of the multiplication can be divided by 2^13 to get a 3.13 (or 19.13?) bit fixed point value. If you mix different kind of values it becomes confusing. So it all depends on if you want to keep it as fixed point values or go to floats sometimes or what.

Comment: I think the strange part is `I understand there they needs to be normalized` - Why? How do you understand it? Why do you have to normalize them? Just stay in floating point - if user has some strange sensor that has some bias-ed zero or outputs data in q13 format - the user will know about it and he will tune kp in your controller. Also `convert from integer` - A strict interpretation of values you presented: `2.7056` is not an `int`(-eger), but a `double` or `float`.

Comment: @KamilCuk The problem is that not everything is a PC and using floating point is dreadfully slow on any CPU which doesn't come with a FPU. That is, from Cortex M3 and downwards.

Comment: The possibility of having a constant error with fixed point arithmetic controllers is one of the trade-offs you'll have to accept. By choosing Q15 you've effectively shrunken your dynamic range to the limits of a 16bit integer variable. If this isn't sufficient you've to either choose a bigger fixed point format (e.g. Q31) or one with a dynamic range like float. Also you're giving away precision by choosing an even factor. You're limiting the proportional gain to 0.676 (22164) instead of using the whole range up to 1.0.

Comment: @Vinci There is no point in having vastly better resolution than what the real world limitations allow though. If you are reading results through a 12 bit ADC, it doesn't matter the slightest if your calculations use 16, 32 or 64 bit, fixed or floating point.

Comment: Absolutely. If the mentioned error of e(n)=2 directly translates to an ADC reading the whole discussion is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I use the result of the PID as a feedforward on another control loop. I sum the PID output to the set point of the second loop. The set point of the second control loop is an integer number between 0...2^12 (is a peripheral, so the range is fixed). Now what is difficult to understand is how to correlate the numbers. If I sum without conversion (without dividing by 2^13), the system is not stable (the feedforward has huge gain). If I don't divide, the compensation is null.

Comment: @Lundin The STM32F4 has an FPU, hasn't it ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean yes. I could use float version, of course. I only want to go deep in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on control theory, but here is a practical approach.

Those float numbers are just generic numbers with no meaning until you define one. Typically you would multiply them with a meaningful constant at compile-time, then cast to fixed point, also at compile-time.

This constant should be something such as the resolution of a PWM, ADT or whatever it is you wish the integer values to represent. Define what exactly the values represent, like for example PWM duty cycle ticks. Use a unit convenient for the MCU.

You should have something along the lines of this:

```
#define kp (int32_t)(2.7056f * PID_SCALE)
#define ki (int32_t)(0.0850f * PID_SCALE)
#define kd (int32_t)(0.0000f * PID_SCALE)
```

(Note: this may or may not force/need a floating point lib to get linked with your program, even though you aren't actually using it.)

Where PID_SCALE is some suitable integer constant. Note that if you are looking for a pure fixed point regulator, you shouldn't be using floating point types anywhere except in the above definitions. I suspect that your problems could be related to that, in which case the problem is with the C code implementation rather than the control theory and math.

In pseudo code you'd end up with something like:

```
p = kp * error
check that p is in range, if not set it to min/max

i = prev_i + error
check that i is in range, if not set it to min/max
prev_i = i
i = ki * i

pi = (p + i) / PID_SCALE
```

This way you multiply each term with the constant, keep track of `I` separately, and divide when the calculation is done.

Answer (score 0):

When developing your fixed point PID compensator, the `2^13` will be selected based on your desirable tuning range for each of the parameters as well as the size/range of the error signal. Either case, the output from the PID compensator will be -32768...32767 (or -1.0 to 1.0), which will be directly scaled to fit into the control output (i.e. 12-bit PWM register 0 to 4096, 0 to 100%).

Typically, you do not convert the output of the PID compensator back to floating point, except maybe for telemetry purposes.

Also, as others have stated, watch out for overflow/saturation points in the compensator itself, or one term may dominate your output.

Comment: Hi @Francesco if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.